# Updating an iPhone app to Universal app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad, ios-universal-app

I have one existing app for iphone with tabBarController and NavigationController.Now i want to make it universal app with splitView functionality for ipad.
Now my question is can i take another mainWindow for ipad or give condition for ipad in appDelegate?which is the better way to make it universal with splitView functionlity.

please suggest me the way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hey You can take two different `MainWindow` for `iPhone and iPad`.

You can set `Main nib file base name` = `MainWindow` for iPhone

And `Main nib file base name(iPad)` = `MainWindow-iPad` for iPad

This will be available in your `info.plist`